# Load html.erb from different path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my view I usually do something like this

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/p" %>
```

and _p.html.erb file is places into myapp/app/view/shared/_p.hrml.erb.
Let's suppose I want to place this file in a cutomem folder like myapp/custom/_p.html.erb how can I load the folder custom into my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `append_view_path`:

```
ActionController::Base.append_view_path("myapp/custom")
```